# Jquery Ajax - Setting a variable in ajax response

Tags: jquery

I am trying to set a variable called success_var in response to ajax call, but it does set and returns zero. The other problem is the ajax is being called twice. Iy returns success call bacl twice. My php script this is checkdate, echoes a text success or fail which is sent in reponse. The code is

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

$jq('#updateprogress').submit(function() {


var day = $jq('#d_<?php echo $goalsnow->type; ?>').val();

// alert(input_data);

var month = $jq('#m_<?php echo $goalsnow->type; ?>').val();

var year = $jq('#y_<?php echo $goalsnow->type; ?>').val();
var email_dp = '<?php echo $email_dp; ?>';
var success_var = 0;
$jq.ajax({
type: "POST",
url:  "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/checkdate.php",
data: {day:day,month:month,year:year,email_dp:email_dp},
dataType:"html",
success: function(msg){
$jq('<div>').html(msg).appendTo('div#error_msg').hide().fadeIn('slow');
success_var=1;
}
});
alert(success_var);

return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Ajax call is an asynchronous request. 
So you call alert method before the value of success_var set to 1.

try this:

```
success: function(msg){
$jq('<div>').html(msg).appendTo('div#error_msg').hide().fadeIn('slow');
   success_var=1;
   alert(success_var);
}
});
```